# How to write XMP metadata to a PSD? (JAVA)

Tags: java, image, apache, psd, xmp

I have a photoshop file that I want to be able to change 2 text values with a java program. Opening the PSD with a text editor I can find the text that I want to change. [LayerText Eighty, LayerText Nine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OS8nC.jpg)
I hid some content with blue for privacy reasons. If I use exiftool gui i see [this][2]. So I assumed it was under TextLayerText. In photoshop they are [text layers.][3] I did some research and heard about Sanselan in apache commons. I can find the same code that I found in my [text editor][4].

```
File imageFile = new File(fileField.getText());
                File outputFile = new File(fileField.getText().split("\\.")[0] + ".png");
                BufferedImage image = Sanselan.getBufferedImage(imageFile);
                logArea.append("--- XMP Metadata ----\n");
                logArea.append(Sanselan.getXmpXml(imageFile));
                Map params = new HashMap();
                params.put("TextLayerText", "");
                Sanselan.writeImage(image, outputFile, ImageFormat.IMAGE_FORMAT_PNG, params);
```

This is the code I currently have. It declares 2 files first is input and 2nd is output. It gets the XMP and prints it out. I create a params Map but my error is.

```
org.apache.sanselan.ImageWriteException: Unknown parameter: TextLayerText
```

The goal of this program is to modify the 2 text layers and render the png from this. It renders the png file if i leave the params blank, and i can read the params with Sanselan.getXmpXml. I am struggling to find a way to change them though. I put all pictures [in one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OS8nC.jpg) because of my reputation I can't post more than 2 links.

Comment: Do you expect the PSD pixel data to change, after changing the text in the XMP? I'm afraid you are going to be disappointed in that case... Anyway, the  allowed parameter names for the `params` map are defined in [SanselanConstants](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/sanselan/SanselanConstants.html).

Comment: Ah, that's disappointing then, from what I have been reading the PSD is not a rendered image and that value in the metadata holds the text value and is rendered as an image once the file is saved as an actual image type.

Comment: A PSD file may include [many things](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/), however, what most PSD readers/viewers (and I'm sure Sanselan does this) is simply read and display the "merged/composite image" which is normal (static/pre-rendered) pixel data.